# help me prove this inequality of the two given sequences of natural numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, proof-verification

$\{p(n)\},\{q(n)\},\{p'(n)\},\{q'(n)\}$ are $4$ sequences of natural numbers satisfying $p(n)\le p'(n) \le q'(n)\le q(n),$ $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} q(n)=\infty,$$ $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} q'(n)=\infty.$$

Given that  $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{{q(n)-p(n)}\over{q'(n)-p'(n)}}=d\gt 0,$$

how do I prove that $$\{k\in \mathbb N :p'(n)\lt k\lt q'(n)\}\subseteq \{k\in \mathbb N : p(n)\lt k\lt q(n)\}?$$

From the limit of the ratio we can say $$\color{purple}{|q'(n)-p'(n)|\le d|q(n)-p(n)|}$$ and from the given relations we can say $\{p(n) , q(n)\}$ have more numbers between them including $p'(n)$ and $q'(n)$ than $\{p'(n) , q'(n)\}$ and so the inequality holds.

My only problem is whether the $\color{purple}{line}$  is correct or not or if something more needs to be added to make it clear.

Thank you.

Comment: This follows immediately from the first inequalities you stated.  It has nothing to do with the ratio.

Comment: @David : so the ratio limit is totally redundant for this question.?

Comment: Yes.$\,\! \,\!$

Comment: Think about what it means to prove that one set is contained in a second set: one must prove that if $k$ is an element of the first set, then $k$ is an element of the second set. So, given that $p'(n)<k<q'(n)$ (so that $k$ is in the first set), can you prove that $p(n)<k<q(n)$ (so that $k$ is in the second set)? (By the way, it's not clear whether your sets depend upon a parameter $n$, or whether both set definitions should include "there exists $n\in\Bbb N$ such that".)